# Trying to find a good javascript function for hmac-sha1

Tags: html, twitter, hmacsha1

So i have been searching the web for a javascript source for an Hmac-sha1 algorithm. I saw Crypto's but i cant seem to get it to work, mainly because it has no idea what crypto means. (i copied the .js script functions into my script file)  
 http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/  
I have my base64 encoded function already. that i got from here: 
http://nerds-central.blogspot.com/2007/01/fast-scalable-javascript-and-vbscript.html


btw this for a twitter application using the new OAuth system.

any help or links to where i can find anything on this would be helpful 
If you need me to elaborate let me know. thank you!

Comment: crypto is an abbreviation for cryptography.

Comment: It was in this function, but i with jssha i dont have to add several files to make it work. 
(function(){var e=Crypto,a=e.util,b=e.charenc,d=b.UTF8,c=b.Binary;...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but 'jssha' seems to have added HMAC support to its SHA-X library recently:

http://jssha.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks this looks like it will work. still getting use to how this oauth thing has to be done lol Thanks again!